# Why abstract index notation should not be confused with the Ricci calculus?

Tags: notation, tensors

Considering [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455574/166945), it is mentioned that the range of indices $a, b, c,\dots$ are seen as abstract and coordinate-free and linear operations can be represented with them; and the range of indices $i, j, k,\dots$ have numerical values and are subject to Einstein summation. What would be the problem of using the same range of indices, say $i, j, k,\dots$ as abstract as in $T_{ijkl}$ and refering to components only when a coordinate frame is applied, like $T_{ijkl}{\bf E}_{ijkl}$ since I always need a coordinate frame to know the values of the scalar components of the tensor?
In other words, what would be the problem of considering $T_{ijkl}$ both as abstract tensor and multidimensional array of scalars depending on the context? Or why [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) should not be confused with Ricci calculus as said in the first paragraph of the article?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any issues in doing this. The abstract index notation is more a shift of perspective than anything else. In effect, it allows one to do Ricci-style computations without picking a basis, by deciding that the indices are just labels for the different factors in the tensor product. A contraction in the abstract notation would be written the same way, structurally, as the same contraction with a coordinate system fixed and the indices concrete and no longer abstract.

In the Ricci calculus, a contraction indicates a literal summation. Since this requires numbers, it also requires a coordinate system to be chosen. In the abstract notation, a contraction indicates a basis-independent trace operation being applied, which reduces to the aforementioned summation whenever a specific basis is fixed.

Really, the abstract index notation is nothing more than the observation that almost all of the Ricci calculus remains intact if one does *not* choose a basis. There's a great deal of meaning in the *structure* of the index expressions which is not basis dependent.