# Verifying that $D_t V_a = \left\{ \frac{\partial V_k}{\partial t} + g^{ij} H H_{jk} V_i \right\} F_a^k$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214456010) paper and I found difficulty to develop the equation on the final of the page $3$, i.e.,

> $$D_t V_a = \left\{ \frac{\partial V_k}{\partial t} + g^{ij} H H_{jk} V_i \right\} F_a^k.$$

I'm sure that the notation used in the paper is the same of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3189815) because I could compute $D_a V_b$ as follows

\begin{align*}
 \nabla_a V_b &= (\nabla_a \omega_V)(F_b) = \nabla_a (\langle V, F_b \rangle) - \langle V, \nabla_a F_b \rangle = \langle \nabla_a V, F_b \rangle + \langle V, \nabla_a F_b \rangle - \langle V, \nabla_a F_b \rangle\\
 &= \langle \nabla_a V, F_b \rangle = \langle \nabla_{F_a} V, F_b \rangle = \langle \nabla_{F_a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} V, F_b^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \rangle = F_a^i F_b^j \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} V, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle\\
 &= F_a^i F_b^j \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \left\langle V, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle \right) - \left\langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle \right) = F_a^i F_b^j (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} \omega_V) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right)\\
 &= F_a^i F_b^j \nabla_i V_b,
\end{align*}
where $\omega_X$ the $1$-form dual to a vector field $X$, i.e., $\omega_X(Y) := \langle X,Y \rangle$ for every vector field $Y$ on $M$ and fix the following notation: $\nabla_a X_b := (\nabla_a \omega_X) (F_b)$, but I couldn't compute $D_t V_a$ as you can read (see the evolution equation for $F_a^i$ and the notation of indexes on page $3$ of the paper for a better understanding of the computations below):
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial V_a}{\partial t} &= (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \omega_V) (F_a) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \langle V, F_a \rangle \right) - \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_a \rangle\\
 &= \left\langle \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}, F_a \right\rangle = \left\langle \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \left( \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \langle V, F_b \rangle F_b \right), F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= \left\langle \left( \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \frac{\partial \langle V, F_b \rangle}{\partial t} F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle \frac{\partial F_b}{\partial t} \right), F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= \left\langle \left( \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \left( (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \omega_V) (F_b) + \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_b \rangle \right) F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle \frac{\partial F_b}{\partial t} \right), F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= \left\langle \left( \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \left( (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \omega_V) (F_b) + \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_b \rangle \right) F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle g^{ij} H h_{kj} F_b^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \right), F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \omega_V) (F_a) +  \left\langle \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \left( \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_b \rangle \right) F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle g^{ij} H h_{kj} F_b^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= (\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \omega_V) (F_a^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}) + \left\langle \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \left( \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_b \rangle \right) F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle g^{ij} H h_{kj} F_b^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, F_a \right\rangle\\
 &= \frac{\partial V_k}{\partial t} F_a^k + \left\langle \sum\limits_{b=1}^n \left( \langle V, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} F_b \rangle \right) F_b + \langle V, F_b \rangle g^{ij} H h_{kj} F_b^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, F_a \right\rangle
\end{align*}

I would like to know how I can compute the evolution equation for $V_a$. Thanks in advance!