# Closed/exactness of covariant derivatives of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Is there a condition on vector fields $X$ and/or the underlying manifold $(M,g)$ such that $\nabla_X \omega$ is a closed differential form? That is, $d \nabla_X \omega = 0$. Let us assume for now that $\omega = df$, but if there is a more situations where a result holds then I would also be curious to know. Similar to this kind of question

> [When is the Hessian contracted with a vector field a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813323/when-is-the-hessian-contracted-with-a-vector-field-a-closed-form?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have you tried to do the calculation yourself?

Comment: I've calculated a specific example I was interested in and got some truly horrendous relations. I am quite certain now that the answer to my question is a definitive "No", but I'll leave this up in case somebody has a lot of insight that I missed out and actually finds something.